# Spring Security two web sites sharing same remember-me login

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

Has anyone tried to do this and gotten it to work?  I have tried to set them up accessing the same database on the same server using the same remember-me key but it will not work. Is there something I may be missing? Is this even possible if they are completely separate war files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main consideration is the domains and paths under which the applications are accessed and whether the remember-me cookie can be shared among them.

By default the cookie path is set to be the context path of the application, so you cannot share a cookie between two different applications unless you change this. Even then, if the domains do not match, the browser will refuse to send the cookie.

You need to override the `setCookie` method in `AbstractRememberMeServices` to avoid setting a specific path for the cookie. If the domains do not exactly match you will also have to call the `Cookie.setDomain` method. You can use something like `setDomain(".foo.com")` to share the cookie between `a.foo.com` and `b.foo.com`. See the Javadoc for more details.